# $all query returning no result

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying a query of this kind on my Auction collection, the objective is to return all documents with: `item == 2770` and a `dump == ObjectId("5104f03a46ab64d404000000") or ObjectId("51067f4946ab644003000000") or ObjectId("5106924e46ab64c81c000000")`.

```
{
    item: 2770,
    dump: {
        $all: [
            ObjectId("5104f03a46ab64d404000000"),
            ObjectId("51067f4946ab644003000000"),
            ObjectId("5106924e46ab64c81c000000")
        ]
    }
}
```

This query doesn't return me anything, however this one (note that I use a dump contained in the $all operator), return me a list of document. Am I ignoring something about the $all operator behavior?

```
{
    item: 2770,
    dump: ObjectId("5106924e46ab64c81c000000")
}
```

Here is an example of document in my Auction collection

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5106924e46ab64c81c000237"),
    auc: 1560105766,
    item: 2770,
    owner: "Ozrael",
    bid: 450000,
    buyout: 450000,
    quantity: 20,
    timeLeft: "VERY_LONG",
    dump: ObjectId("5106924e46ab64c81c000000"),
    faction: "horde",
    bidPricePerUnit: 22500,
    buyoutPricePerUnit: 22500
}
```

Comment: Probably you should use `$in` operator instead of `$all` here.

Comment: Yes, using $in in your example is an issue too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the wrong operator for the query, [$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/) is matching an entire array, as said in the documentation.

The correct operator to match documents that contain either of the specified values is [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/)

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `$all`, every document of your result set is supposed to have all the mentioned values. The document in your example should have the following structure to be found:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5106924e46ab64c81c000237"),
    auc: 1560105766,
    item: 2770,
    owner: "Ozrael",
    bid: 450000,
    buyout: 450000,
    quantity: 20,
    timeLeft: "VERY_LONG",
    dump: [
            ObjectId("5104f03a46ab64d404000000"),
            ObjectId("51067f4946ab644003000000"),
            ObjectId("5106924e46ab64c81c000000")
          ],
    faction: "horde",
    bidPricePerUnit: 22500,
    buyoutPricePerUnit: 22500
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was struck by stupidity, the operator I must use is $in.

Comment: You are not giving the answer to the question, rather you are asking to change the question itself according to the answer OP has got. That simply doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Even if he didn't answer the question his post led me to the correct operator.

Comment: Re-read the topic name. I've given simple explanation to it, don't you think?

Comment: @VyacheslavSermyazhko.. What do you think? I gave the answer(in the comment) without reading the question? I'm not saying that you didn't gave the explanation. But you just pointed out the change in the document required, whereas the answer should be what operator to use instead of `$all` given the actual document. Now you say, does it make sense?

Comment: @RohitJain Do you feel the difference between questions "Why it doesn't work" and "How to make it work"? I answered the 1st one, and you answered the 2nd one.

Comment: @RohitJain By the way, I did NOT suggest to change the document structure. I showed the structure suitable for that query in order to clarify the way $all works.